# Realtime app with signalR and ampesand-reactjs

Tags: signalr, reactjs, react-router, ampersand.js

Im going to build some kind of voting-app with .net signalR (and .NET Web Api) backend and Reactjs and Ampersand.js on the client.
I have a couple of questions regarding this setup:

- What is the differense between using React-router and Ampersand-router?
  Will it be easier to manage browser-state if I go with Ampersand-router?
- Does anyone have an alternative choice of clientstack when it is importaint to have an organized and responsive client in a high intensity realtime environment (High frequency voting).